# StringFormat for DateTime is not working with MultiBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multibinding

I have this code :

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} created on {0} by">
                    <Binding Path="CreationDate" StringFormat="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </LabeledLabel.Content>
</Label>
```

`OUTPUT`

I always get this `created on 21/09/2014 00:00:00 by`

I tried `StringFormat="d"`, but it didn't work too.

What's the problem with my code ?

Comment: You've only got one `Binding Path`, so you'll only ever get the date and time. See the [MultiBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see what you should be doing. Basically, you need to add a `Binding` element for your person data type.

Comment: How can you *See the MultiBinding Class page on MSDN*??? You click the link. Either way, I have now added an answer for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've only got one `Binding Path`, so you'll only ever get the date and time. Basically, you need to add a `Binding` element for your person data type. It should be more like this:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} created on {0:dd/MM/yyyy} by {1}">
                    <Binding Path="CreationDate" />
                    <Binding Path="SomeEmployeeObject.Name" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </LabeledLabel.Content>
</Label>
```

Note that you can also set the `DateTime StringFormat` using the `MultiBinding.StringFormat` property, instead of adding another on the first `Binding` object. You also needed to add the `{1}` to the end of the `MultiBinding.StringFormat` so that it would output the second (person related) value.

Please see the [MultiBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information.

---

UPDATE >>>

> I don't understand why putting the StringFormat property on the MultiBinding element has a different behaviour compared to the first element

It doesn't... I could have left it there, but I moved it because you were already using a `StringFormat`. Using `StringFormat` property on a `MultiBinding` is virtually the same as using the `string.Format` method. Using the method, this is equivalent to what you had in your XAML:

```
string.Format("created on {0:dd/MM/yyyy} by ", someDate);
```

And this is equivalent to what I put in your XAML:

```
string.Format("created on {0:dd/MM/yyyy} by {1}", someDate, someEmployee.Name);
```

Hopefully, you can now see the difference.

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why putting the StringFormat property on the MultiBinding element has a different behaviour compared to the first element !

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it doesn't. It was simply moved into the MultiBinding element to use a single `String.Format` instead of two.